# Unable to Jest Test constant variable having ternary operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using jest react testing library to unit test my application. I am unable to unit test my constant file containing ternary operator for a constant variable.

Code to be tested:

```
export const ApplicationConstant = {
    type: process.env.REACT_APP_NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',
}
```

Unit test code:

```
import {ApplicationConstant} from './application.constant.js';
test('Check application type',()=>({
    expect(ApplicationConstant.type).toBe('production'); //Fails

});
```

How to get 100% coverage for ternary operator for constant file containing constants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {ApplicationConstant} from './application.constant.js';
test('Check application type',()=>({
    Object.defineProperty(ApplicationConstant, 'type', {
        value: 'production',
    })
    expect(ApplicationConstant.type).toBe('production'); 

});
```